# Eclipse IDE view gone - how to get it back

Tags: eclipse

I basically have multiple monitors and did some changes today. As such, the views on one of my monitors (specifically the console view) is no longer there. I can't seem to find a way to get it back.

The console view appears in `Window -> Open view`, and this menu option moves focus from the other open views, but the console view does not appear on screen. This probably means it's positioned outside of the monitors...

How can I get the view back?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

two option:

```
window -> New Window         //Opens with no editors, but preserves views layout
window -> reset perspective  //Keep editors, but resets layout view
```

If i understood your description correctly - you'll get what you want.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a better alternative than resetting the perspective because it's really nicely setup now. I have about 20 views all aligned to the proper screens, and so on. If not, then you will get the answer.

Comment: I give up, yours was the only solution I could find. It's too bad, but I guess that's the nature of multiple monitors and adjusting which one goes where :(

Comment: For future reference: you can save your current perspective setup, then switch back to the original and reset it. That way you can quickly recreate most of your previous setup.

Comment: Actually there is a way to solve this problem without resetting the perspective! It's a bit complicated but that's worth it if you've done a lot of setting up you don't want to redo. See my answer.

Comment: In my case, "Reset Perspective" doesn't work. "new Window" works! then I close the old misbehaving window and continue with my work. Thanks! :)

Comment: It worked for me. +1 for your quick fix. However, I would want to know the root cause behind the same. Thanks

Comment: in my case, the outline was not showing anymore, the reset perspective (java) worked thanks!

Comment: Don't reset your perspective!  Just follow the answer provided by @cyber-monk below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010366/2812695

Answer (score 23):

I managed to return my gone view **without resetting the perspective**!
I opened `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`, searched for "outline" there (the view was Outline) and found it (precisely org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline) inside a `children` tag which had an attribute `visible="false"`. I removed that attribute and also `<tags>Minimized</tags>` inside the `children` tag, saved the file, started Eclipse, and that was it, my view returned!

Comment: The solution works fine for temporary use or at least to retrieve the "part stack". However, when minimizing the "part stack", the elements are gone away again. It is highly recommanded to create a new part stack and to move all views to tnis new one.

Comment: +1 for pointing out where Eclipse stores the workbench state. I was having issues with views missing after trying to move them back to the main window from a secondary window. After mucking around in the workbench.xmi I was able to get the views back. Make sure you close Eclipse *before* messing with the xmi... otherwise your changes will be overridden when you exit eclipse.

Comment: My 2 cents. This was very helpful, in my case it wasn't caused by `visible="false"`. Instead, the `children` attribute that had my missing file was nested inside of `<children xsi:type="basic:PartStack" [blah blah blah] >` all by its lonesome self.  The rest of the files I had open were in another set of `<children xsi:type="basic:PartStack" [blah blah blah] >`. I moved the `children` node with my missing file up into the `basic:PartStack` section with the rest of its friends. I was trying to split my editor with the file and let go before completing the drag.

Comment: I think this worked - or otherwise I was not able to see the Outline view before while suddenly I can - for some mysterious reason related to the stars and their orbits. One can never be sure with Eclipse (kepler in  my case)

Comment: In my case, I had reconfigured my monitors.  I was using 3 wide, so desktop X > 2000.  I am testing out a single portrait mode monitor, so now desktop X < 1500.  You must close eclipse, modify the xml.  I changed the value of height, width, x, and y so it would show up on the screen.  Saved xml, relaunched eclipse.  I had to reopen the view, but alas, it was visble.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen and my Outline view wouldn't show. Resetting perspectives didn't work. I couldn't find any visible attributes in the workbench.xmi file so I tried changing toBeRendered from false to true but that didn't work either. Ultimately I deleted the file and let Eclipse re-create it and my Outline view showed up as soon as I re-opened my project.

Answer (score 12):

Use **`CTL+F7`** to cycle through the Eclipse Views, select one that is on the hidden detached view group, then press **`ALT+<space>, M`** and use the keyboard arrows to position this window onto your active screen.

Comment: Since you said it was positioned outside of the monitors positions I thought you must have detached it.  If that's not the case ignore my post.

Comment: It is detached. But detached Eclipse views (windows) don't have the same options as standard windows.

Comment: I've tested Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 and I can use CTL+F7 to cycle through the Eclipse Views (detached or attached) and then use ALT+SPACE,m to move the window.

Comment: I tried this in Windows 7 in a workspace where the Ant view had disappeared like in the question, and it didn't work. It does work when the view is detatched but still on screen, though.

Comment: In my case, I organize the perspective placing the editor view, maximized, in one monitor, and all other views organized in another window, that goes on the other monitor. Sometimes when I try to restore (unmaximize) the second window, it disappears. Using Ctrl+F7 to select one view in that window I saw a small vertical line on the screen. It was the window, that was restored to that dimensions. I could then grab the "corner" of the line and drag to a desired size. And now maximizing and restoring works as intended.

Answer (score 10):

Slightly related... I just had a case where my editor disappeared and would not reappear. I could try to open files but not see them anywhere (the file would be successfully parsed by the "Outline" view). Simply resetting the perspective didn't work. Nor did Window -> New Editor. To fix I had to do this:

1. Window -> Close Perspective. (I actually did Close All Perspectives in a fit of rage)
2. Window -> Open Perspective. (C/C++ in my case)
3. Window -> Reset Perspective.

BTW, I'm running Juno.

Comment: Great.  All I had to do was close my perspective and then re-open it and the errant views returned.  Eclipse 4.2.2.  Thanks.

Comment: same issue.. followed above step but still editor not visible :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're just missing a view, you can use the menu item: `Window`->`Show View`->`Console`. No need to reset the perspective.

Alternatively, Ctrl-3 and type *Console* <enter>.

Comment: That the issue, the view doesnt' appear because it's outside the visible space of my monitor. It appears, but I can't see it because it's outside the bounds of my monitor.

Answer (score 2):

This is a naïve answer and may not be possible in every case, but it worked for me and turned out to be less hassle than I thought:

I simply changed my OS's monitor setup to bring the windows back to within reach, dragged them back to the main screen, changed my monitor setup back to reality, and dragged the windows to my monitor's new position. Certainly easier than setting my perspective back up from scratch!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by removing the attribute `toBeRendered="false"` from the element with `elementId="org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack"` in the `workbench.xmi` file.

Answer (score 2):

This has been one of the most annoying and long-lasting bugs in Eclipse for me. I still don't know why this happens, but my solution (similar to @cyber-monk) is the following:

1. Open Window -> Show View -> Console (activates the console window, but it's still hidden).
2. Alt-Space (activates the context menu).
3. Select maximize (actually shows the console window).

This works, since I have the console window open on the second screen as in the question. Not sure if this bug happens when console is not in a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

Tested under Windows 7 with "Console"-view

Select in menu Window -> Show View -> Console

The main window becomes inactive and invisible Console-window is now active.

Now, press Alt+Space combination and somewhere on main Display appears small menu with window-controls.

Select "Maximize" and the hidden window becomes maximized on main Display. Now just drag the view with mouse  to the main eclipse window.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the 'reset perspective' approach does not work. As an alternative to those who are building Android apps or such. Try Window > Open Perspective > Others > Java (Default). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the suggestions below, but none of them worked. Here is what finally worked for me. 
1. Go to the workspace folder and change its file name.
2. Open eclipse and accept the new workspace.
3. Import projects into the new workspace.

If you're like me and have a lot of projects its a pain but it worked, and I get to leave out a few projects that I don't need anymore.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I opened a new window and it solved my problem of my editor failing to open a file - resetting perspective and deleting indexes did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did Window->Perspective->Reset Perspective on all of my Perspectives within Eclipse Mars, and it did the trick in restoring all of my views.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file which is invisible and click on any other file to open.
And then open the invisible file.  It will get opened in the editor.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, he is talking about getting back the console window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window -> New Window         //Opens with no editors, but preserves views layout
window -> reset perspective  //Keep editors, but resets layout view
```

If i understood your description correctly - you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Ctrl-F Find and Replace window would not display.
Tried everything. What worked for me:

- assign Ctrl-F to another action like Search
- press Ctrl-F
- a popup menu allows you to choose which action
- select Find and Replace (which actually shows the popup!!!!)
- Close the Find and Replace Window
- Unbind the key from Search