# Eclipse IDE no view at all - how to get it back

Tags: eclipse

When I start Eclipse I get nothing. Not a single view. Similar to my [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010334/eclipse-ide-view-gone-how-to-get-it-back) except that now I have absolutely nothing at all. I don't have a menu to be able to even select window -> New Window or window -> reset perspective. The screen is completely other then the application running in my taskbar.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which O.S.? Which download was it? Which JRE and desktop environment? How are you launching it? You need to give information to get anything other than guesses.

Comment: I don't believe that's relevant to this question because for example in the other SO question I linked it was not relevant at all. Sometimes it's best to reduce the information and keep only what's relevant. That being said it's Eclipse Luna, Windows 10, JRE 8. Let me know if that helps you in any way...